# Links not working in IE and Firefox with jquery generated markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm writing a javascript app that dynamically generates buttons that lead users to links about different products.

They look like this:

[image: buttons generated by app]

The problem is when they're generated the links contained within them work in chrome but not in IE or Firefox.

Here's the HTML:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="button-class">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code I use to generate them:

**JQUERY**

```
buttons: function(num) {
    $(".button-class").html("<div class='text-center'><ul class='list-inline'><li><button class='btn btn-success'><a href=" + state.greens[num].website + " target='_blank'>Company Website</a></button></li> <li><button class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>View the Label</button></li></ul></div>");
    if (state.greens[num].link !== false) {
        $(".button-class ul").append("<li><button class='btn btn-success'><a href=" + state.greens[num].link + " rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>Get It On Amazon</a></button></li>");
    }

    if (state.greens[num].review !== false) {
        $(".button-class ul").append("<li><button class='btn btn-success'><a href=" + state.greens[num].review + " target='_blank'>Read The Review</a></button></li>");
    }
},
```

buttons is part of an object called display and is called by display.buttons();

The two if statements check to see if certain types of links exist within a product's object and then appends them to the UL if the ydo.

The buttons generate correctly but they don't open up the links when clicked in Firefox and IE (maybe Safari but I haven't checked).

What's more confusing to me is that the html being generated looks semantically correct.

For example this is the html shown in the Firefox debugger that's not working:

[image: firefox debugger]

Doesn't make sense to me.

If you want to go to a live version of the page you can see it here:  [superfood picker](http://www.healthkismet.com/superfood-picker/)

Then go to the last section that reads "Click On A Product's Detail Page To Learn More" and looks like this:

[image: Where to go in app]

Click on one of the products and it'll take you to the buttons that I'm talking about.

Comment: I think that you can get the problem with the window blocker of the browsers. Firefox and IE have got. If the solution that I post in answer don't works to you, maybe your problem is the blockers. Try to setup the targets in the blockers whitelist.

Answer (score 2):

It's not semantically correct because you need to wrap in quotes the href

```
buttons: function(num) {
    $(".button-class").html("<div class='text-center'><ul class='list-inline'><li><button class='btn btn-success'><a href='" + state.greens[num].website + "' target='_blank'>Company Website</a></button></li> <li><button class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>View the Label</button></li></ul></div>");
    if (state.greens[num].link !== false) {
        $(".button-class ul").append("<li><button class='btn btn-success'><a href='" + state.greens[num].link + "' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>Get It On Amazon</a></button></li>");
    }

    if (state.greens[num].review !== false) {
        $(".button-class ul").append("<li><button class='btn btn-success'><a href='" + state.greens[num].review + "' target='_blank'>Read The Review</a></button></li>");
    }
},
```

Note that's it's best if you change double quotes instead single quotes and viceversa.

Comment: In the example I provided the href address was wrapped in quotes so I don't understand your point.

Comment: This: `<a href=" + state.greens[num].review + "` is not like this `<a href='" + state.greens[num].review + "'`

Comment: so should it be <a href= " + state.greens[num].review + " ?

Comment: Read please. Pay attention when you read. You must to write with single quotes + double quotes. See the code I write in answer